# API limitation (200 Records)- Need javascript counter to get all records

Tags: javascript, loops, counter

I'm getting records as a JSON object from an API with a limitation of 200 records. I need to get from 800 to 1200 records, depending on the day.

This (below) kind of works except, for obvious reasons, it's grabbing the same 200 records with each iteration. I end up with one JSON object with 1200 records but records 1, 201, 401, 601 etc. are all the same.
I feel like a counter is needed here but I can't figure out how to implement it.
Any help or pointed in the right direction is appreciated.
Thank you!

- [Javascript SDK API](https://help.zwidgets.com/help/latest/ZOHO.CRM.API.html#.searchRecord)
- [More detailed REST API](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v3/search-records.html)

```
const iteration = new Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
const dealRecords = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < iteration.length; i++) {
  SOMECOMPANY.API.searchRecord({
    Entity: "Greeting",
    Type: "criteria",
    Query: "(Text:equals:Hay)",
  }).then(function (data) {
    dealRecords.push({ data });
  });
}
console.log(dealRecords);
```

Comment: How you do this will depend on how the API handles pagination. Can you include the API you're using in your question?

Comment: Ahh. I see thanks. I just included the link to the API.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to offset the results you are getting by using an offset or pagination parameter (or anything similar).

The exact way of doing this will depend on the API you are using. Twitter for example provides you with a pagiantion token, while others might expose a query param to offset the results.

Comment: Thank you. I just included the link to the API

Answer (score 1):

According to the API doc you can insert a page param after the config object. And I think you won't need an array for the loop

Like:

```
for (var page = 1; page < 7; page++) {
            SOMECOMPANY.API.searchRecord({ Entity: "Greeting", Type: "criteria", Query: "(Text:equals:Hay)" }, page)
               ...
        }
```

perhaps with page.toString() because the page param has to be a string.

Or you can try to change the perPage param and get just one page with all you need.

```
SOMECOMPANY.API.searchRecord({ Entity: "Greeting", Type: "criteria", Query: "(Text:equals:Hay)" }, "1", "1200")
``
```

Comment: Thanks. Both of those work but they're each still only returning 200 records. I think I need to dig into the API a little more and see if there's a hard limit somewhere.